# Method not returning anything?

Tags: c#

My method for checking login details against a database doesn't seem to return anything. I don't see how it is faulty. Here is the code:

```
connection.Open();
        if (chkRemember.Checked == true)
        {
            loginDetails();
        }
        string command = @"SELECT email, password FROM zc_users WHERE email = '@user';";
        try
        {
            // COMMAND DETAILS
            MySqlCommand email = new MySqlCommand(command, connection);

            // PARAMETERS
            email.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtEmail.Text);

            // READER DETAILS
            MySqlDataReader dr;

            // CHECK DETAILS               
            dr = email.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                string passwordC = dr.GetString(1);
                string saltedPass = Security.HashSalt.CreateHash(txtPassword.Text, passwordC);
                bool match = IsPasswordMatch(passwordC, saltedPass);
                if (match == true)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    string email2 = txtEmail.Text;
                    frmZilent frm = new frmZilent(email2);
                    frm.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    msgEx m = new msgEx();
                    m.Show();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zilent Error: Code ZCx001. Please report this to the Zilent Team. Thanks. " + ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Basically, the email and password are selected from the database and then the password in the `txtPassword` textbox is hashed using the one from the database. The method checks if they are the same, and if they are, it closes the connection and shows the next form.

I either get an error or nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: `I either get an error` what is the error? `nothing happens` have you tried setting breakpoints to see where the code is failing?

Comment: `Method not returning anything`  What method?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange 'Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()' and I tried and found it, but I can't see an error anywhere.

Comment: Google the error, you'll get plenty of answers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " I tried and found it, but I can't see an error anywhere."  Have you not tried to debug your code to see where the error is?

Comment: In what line are you getting that error?

Comment: I don't see any `return` statements. How else would you "return" something (especially since you don't include the complete function)?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has the parameter inside a string literal, therefore the parameter is being interpreted as a string literal, so the value won't be used

You have:

```
 SELECT email, password FROM zc_users WHERE email = '@user';
```

Change to:

```
 SELECT email, password FROM zc_users WHERE email = @user;
```

Note that the apostrophes are missing in the second version.